# Escape characters and @code tag in doc comments

Tags: java, javadoc

I am trying to put the following line

```
{@code object.foo()} is equivalent to {@code Bar.foo(object.baz())}.
```

inside a javadoc comment. IntelliJ tells me that the left bracket after `baz` is an illegal character, and I can get rid of the warning by writing

```
{@code object.foo()} is equivalent to {@code Bar.foo&#40;object.baz())}.
```

instead. The left bracket I replaced by `&#40;` is not the one that gave the warning. This works, but I don't understand why only one of the left brackets in the line causes a problem. Why is this? When do I have to write `&#40;` instead of `(`?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like valid Javadoc. You are saying that there is a function in `Bar` called `foo`, which takes the parameter of type `object.baz()`. Surely you need to replace `object.baz()` with whatever type that method returns?